# A way to model spiky Groot head

Tags: modeling, vertices

I want to model the babygroot from guardians of the galaxy. Here is a picture it should look like.
[image]

My problem is now: how can I model the shape of the spikes on the head. I already tried some versions. In sculpting mode, it is very hard to achieve this, because I want that the spikes are flat on the inside and outside.When I try it looks like this:

[image]

It's not round and flat and the inside is not looking very clear.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Could you show what techniques you have tried and why they failed? Maybe post some screenshots

Comment: You can start with cylinder, inset the top and extrude down to make a tube with bottom. You can then bevel the bottom exterior to round off the bottom part. Then use subsurf and edge crease to detail the top part. You could use curves with profile to make the roots and branches. If you find yourself lost with modeling task you should start with tutorials and simpler shapes to learn about methods so you can build your own approaches to modeling stuff, it's half the fun! :)

Comment: Quite a lot of ways. If box modeling - do what mentioned above, rough forms extruded / whatever in Edit mode, then refine with Subsurf / Multires. If dyntopo sculpting - you can change faloff of the sculpt brush actually in the Curve rollout.